# Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in

Tags: php

I have this problem.

> Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /home/faizalia/public_html/wp-includes/post.php on line 277
>
> Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in /home/faizalia/public_html/wp-includes/post.php on line 277
>
> Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in /home/faizalia/public_html/wp-includes/post.php on line 278

Line 277 :

```
if ( $file && 0 !== strpos( $file, '/' ) && ! preg_match( '|^.:\\\|', $file ) && ( ( $uploads = wp_get_upload_dir() ) && false === $uploads['error'] ) ) {
```

Line 278:

```
$file = $uploads['basedir'] . "/$file";
```

Any solutions?

Comment: What is `$file`?

Comment: the error message is telling you exactly the issue. var_dump() your file to see whats inside it and then you will have a better idea of what property or method you need to call to get the string you are after

Comment: It is this function get_attached_file() in /wp-includes/post.php file. As @JasonJoslin said you must make a var_dump to see what is exactly in $file. So go into /wp-includes/post.php file find this function get_attached_file() and make a dump of $file.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to use

```
$_FILES["myfilename"]["name"];
```

or stringify $file using:

```
(string)$file
```